# Update/Init function or constructor (data not available at construction time)

Tags: c++, class, exception, constructor

I have a class which stores some data.
The problem is that the data is not available at construction time.

Important: The classes are for an SDK with read-only classes (ONLY getters).
The classes only stores data from an online API.

Should I use a pointer and create (allocate) the object, when the data is available?
That would require a constructor that throws an exception when the data is invalid or the constructor fails at some point.

Or should I define a default constructor for the object and implement a update/init function, that initializes the class members.
This solution would create the problem, that I have a "zombie" object until the update function is called.
The second problem would be that you could forget to call the update/init function -> causes first problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the CPP Core Guidelines (http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines):

> C.41: A constructor should create a fully initialized object
>
> Reason A constructor establishes the invariant for a class. A user of a class
> should be able to assume that a constructed object is usable.
>
> Exception If a valid object cannot conveniently be constructed by a
> constructor, use a factory function

followed by:

> C.42: If a constructor cannot construct a valid object, throw an
> exception
>
> Reason Leaving behind an invalid object is asking for
> trouble.

.